# Bound on Chromatic Number with Cheeger Constant

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

Consider a finite graph $G=(V,E)$. If $S\subseteq V$ then $E(S)=|\{uv\in E \,|\, u\in S, v\in V-S\}|$. Then the *Cheeger Constant* $h$ of $G$ is defined to be the minimum of $\frac{E(S)}{|S|}$ among all subsets $S\subseteq E$ such that $|S|\leq |V|/2$. It is supposed to intuitively embody a strong and robust notion of connectedness in a graph and is widely discussed in the study of expanders.

Given its notion of connectedness, we might expect graphs with large $h$ to have large chromatic numbers also. Are there any known (or can we derive) any bounds relating the two constants?

I would be looking for inequalities that go both ways preferably (i.e. lower bounds on $h$ using chromatic numbers as well as lower bounds on Chromatic Number using $h$).

Comment: You probably want $S \subseteq V$ such that $|S| \le |V|/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck in both directions.

On the one hand, a random bipartite graph is a good expander, but has chromatic number $2$. For that matter, $K_{n,n}$ has a Cheeger constant which is linear in $n$ - we just don't think of it as an expander graph because it's in no way sparse.

On the other hand, you can have a graph with high chromatic number which is not even connected (and so has a Cheeger constant of $0$); just take any graph with two components, one of which is your favorite graph with high chromatic number. If you insist on a connected graph, we can still haven an extremely low Cheeger constant, just from adding a few edges between two equally large components with high chromatic number.